# C# File.Read Error: File already in Use by other process

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

i am trying to parse through several Files, while doing so there are some values to ignore and so on. I currently did it with this Code:

```
double[][] rows = File  
         .ReadLines(filepath)  
         .Select(line => line
            .Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  
            .Where(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))   
         .Where(items => items.Any())
         .Select(items => items
           .Select(item => double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))  
           .ToArray())
         .ToArray();
```

But i recently got the Error. After searching in the Internet i found out that

```
 using (FileStream stream = File.Open("path to file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                { DO SOMETHING}
            }
        }
```

Would fix this problem. However i can´t manage to change that Code to my needs. When i try:

```
      using (FileStream stream = File.Open("path to file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    reader.ReadLine().Select(line => line
            .Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  
            .Where(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))   
         .Where(items => items.Any())
         .Select(items => items
           .Select(item => double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))   
           .ToArray())
         .ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

It gives me an error on  ".Split" since its not a known definition for a StreamReader... I know this maight be a really silly questions and pretty easy to solve but i can´t manage it to be done some how...

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Comment: ReadLine() will give you a string and if you write .Select(), inside which you are basically iterating through each character, so you cannot use Split as extension method for a char. Try to read all lines by using ReadAllLines() or ReadLines(), try to put it in a string array and then you can use the .Select() in your code to peform filtering ; Ex: File.ReadAllLines(path) or File.ReadLines(path)

Comment: Replacing this code is not sensible, it will just fail the exact same way.  You'll have to find out what other code or process has this file opened.  Use SysInternals' Handle utility if you have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reader.ReadLine()` will return a string. So when you do `.Select` on this you are projecting this into an `IEnumerable<char>`. You cannot then do `.Split` on a char.

You will need to reformat your code to work by reading one line at a time

So something line this:

```
reader.ReadLine()
      .Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Where(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      .Where(items => items.Any())
      .Select(items => items.Select(item => double.Parse(item.ToString())).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

**Update**

To answer your comment I would most probably change the data structure from `double[][]` to a `List<List<double>>`

If you want to keep the `double[][]` you can do something like this.

You can change the code to add to the list while streaming the file:

```
List<double[]> example = new List<double[]>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    example.Add(reader.ReadLine()
      .Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Where(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      .Where(items => items.Any())
      .Select(item => double.Parse(item.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray());
}


var returnvalue = example.ToArray();
```

**Note**

When making changes like this make sure that the results match the original code.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I understand the Problem you explained well! THANKS, one last questions, before i stored all the informations in the array double[][] rows which has exactly the amount of columns/rows needed for the data. How is this done with this Code you provided? I do not understand that part =/ THANKS FOR YOUR TIME (still learning)

Comment: Thanks again, and yeah i agree with the Note, i will check that. However i have like 7 Functions that are all doing things like this just with other parameters and other files. Basically its a lot of work to change verywhere the structure to List<List<double>>. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with a double[][] ? If not ill just take it and change my Code (since im pretty sure your solutions works fine! THANKS again)

Comment: I have updated the answer, though you may want to look at changing the return object to something like `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>` this way you can change the internal data structure that is used as long as it implements `IEnumerable`

Comment: That is something i was looking for, quite smart actually =O Ill accept the answer in a sec, one last thing :   how do i add the  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to your code? i tried to change the last line to "    .Select(items => items.Select(item => double.Parse(item.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray()).ToList());"  but it has the wrong parameters somewhy =/

Comment: Sorry must have removed that in error - it should just go back where I removed it though.

Comment: I just tried it now it does compile, but when running im getting the following error:"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" "the input character string has the wrong format" directly after the  .InvariantCulture))

Comment: This is weird.. the only difference to the original code is "double.Parse(item.ToString()"   which shouldnt cause the error, though with the original code i dont get that error... mhhh

Comment: That would indicate it is selecting something that is not a double, so it cannot parse the string to a double. Debug the code and see if what value the `item` is.

Comment: the only values in the codes are   "0"   "0,X"  "1" and "NaN" but since the NaN will get removed on forehand it shouldnt be possible... I am debuggin though (which may take a while since its a huge file) EDIT: it crashes at item with the value  46 '.'  what does that mean? the dot (.) made the crash or the 46?

Comment: Made some further tests. it crashes no matter what stands in the .CSV thats being read... I have no clue why =/

Comment: I have updated the code, the double select statement was not needed and was doing the same as your original issue and projecting the string "1.2" to an `IEnumerable<char>` '1', ',' and '2'. I have tested the above code with the input 1;1;1.2;NaN

Comment: I relly appreciate your effort and time!! But i am still getting two Errors when i try to compile your new code.  1 Error: (at example.Add) = .Add(double[]) has some invalid arguments and 2. Errror:(at .ToList()) Cannot convert from list<double>  to double []

Comment: Sorry, it should be `.ToArray()`

Comment: THANK you so much!

Comment: Wooohooo...we got there in the end

Comment: YEAH! THANK YOU SO MUCH, have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `reader.ReadLine()` with `reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)`. Also you can write own your extension method `ReadLines` for the reader class.

Comment: StreamReader has no ReadLines method.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `StreamReader.ReadLines()` doesn't exist, what would be the point in streaming something if you're going to load it all into memory anyway?

Comment: I wrote example inline implementation of ReadLines and I suggest to write it as extension method.

Comment: You could make your answer a little clearer, the OP may not make the leap to write this as an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Is it neccessary to use outer "using"? Try this:

```
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                { your split implementation }
            }
        }
    }

    // now you dont need to close a stream because
    // using statement will handle it for you

    catch // appropriate exception handling
    {

    }
```

Comment: This is true, but does not help with my Problem. I can not manage to implement all the split informations i want to the new reader. (basically all i have to do is transfer the code from the old code (File.ReadLines) to the new with StreamReader, but somehow i can´t get it done =/)